# adding an element to the label bar

Tags: android, label, element, addition

I want to add an element to the label bar in the top right corner.[element like the green square in the top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HVQx.png)
Purpose of this element would be to indicate some app status by changing color (green, yellow or red). It should persist through all the app activities. If anyone has other suggestion on how I should go on about it, I would gladly accept it. Only condition is that it is in the position marked in the picture. the element can be an image (where i would load one of the 3 images) or a textview where I would just change background color, or some other solution.

this is the code where label is defined in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.application.Limiter" android:label="@string/LIMITER_ACTION_BAR_TITLE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a menu item in a new .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/circle_ok"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""/>
</menu>
```

and then added this code to activity:

```
private MenuItem menuItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menu);
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
    return true;
}
```

to change the icon I used:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    switch(status) {
        case 0:
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setIcon(R.drawable.circle_ok);
            break;
        case 1:
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setIcon(R.drawable.circle_warning);
            break;
        case 2:
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setIcon(R.drawable.circle_alarm);
            break;
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

after changing status value invalidateOptionsMenu(); should be called.
This is the result:
[color changes every second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Va5A.png)

thx everyone for help, I hope someone can find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the android [toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar) widget in your main activity layout, below code will give your desired result

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoXmarks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```